Compiler cannot infer types when passing another method as parameter
I'm working with .NET 4.7.2 and have a method defined as follows:
private static Func<byte[], byte[]> Wrap<TInput, TOutput>(Func<TInput, TOutput> action)
{
    // Implementation
}

This method accepts another method as a parameter. However, when I try to call the Wrap method with another method, the compiler throws an error indicating that it cannot infer the types TInput and TOutput from the usage. In this case TInput and TOutput are the input parameter and return type of the method passed to the Wrap method.
Example:
public static int ExampleMethod(string input)
{
    return input.Length;
}

var wrapped = Wrap(ExampleMethod); // The type arguments for method 'Func<byte[],byte[]> Ssi.SDKWrapper.ApiHandlerStorage.Wrap<TInput,TOutput>(Func<TInput,TOutput>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I expected the compiler to infer the types from the ExampleMethod signature. When specified exactly, no errors are thrown. How can I modify the Wrap method so that the types can be inferred correctly? Why is the compiler unable to infer the types?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Is explicit type-arguments okay? e.g. var wrapped = Wrap<string,int>(ExampleMethod) ?

Does your ExampleMethod method have any other overloads - or is it unique?

Stating the types explicitly is okay, but I was hoping there was a way to remove the need of them. Also, I don't expect the wrapped method to have any overloads in the context of the application.

The root-cause of the problem is that passing ExampleMethod relies on the compiler inferring the right delegate-type to use, and the compiler won't automatically default to an open generic Func<>. See here: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/129

@Dai that would make a good answer.
